# Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Range<Int>' and Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'Float'

Tags: ios, swift, class

I got this error. Also, function range could not do this multiplication and division by g for some values that I ranged.How can i could fix this problem?

```
class ballShooter {
    var ballShooter : Int = 0
    var teta = 0 ..< 90
    var v = 0 ..< 100
    var g  = 10
    
    init(ballShooter:Int,teta:Int,v:Int,g:Int) {
        self.ballShooter = ballShooter
        self.teta = teta
        self.v = v
        self.g = g
    }
    
    
    func range(r: Int)->Int {
       let r = v * v * sin(2 * teta) / g
       return r
    }
}
```

Comment: The errors are pretty clear: The default values of `teta` and `v` are **ranges** but the init method has **`Int`** (single value) parameter. And you cannot multiply an Int by a range.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `var teta = 0 ..< 90` you are telling the compiler that the variable `teta` (theta?) contains a half-open Int range from 0 to less than 90. Thus, your initializer needs to take a value of type Range of Int for the `teta` parameter.

Do you really want teta and `v` to contain ranges? Or are you trying to set limits to the values that callers can assign to those variables?

### Edit:

If your goal is to set limits on the legal range of values for a variable, you have to implement that for yourself. Here is some sample code illustrating how you might do that:

```
class Foo {
    
    // This determines the legal range of values for aVal.
    public var validValRange = 50...200
    
    public var aVal: Int {
        set {
            // Make sure the value is in range before updating the internal var
            if validValRange ~= newValue {
                _aVal = newValue
            }
        }
        get {
            // Return the previously validated value.
            return _aVal
        }
    }
    
    // This is a private variable that stores validated values for aVal
    private var _aVal: Int = 0
}
```

You could test it with code like this:

```
let aFoo = Foo()

aFoo.aVal = 52
aFoo.aVal = 500

print(aFoo.aVal)
```

That would print "52" since the value 500 is out of range.

Comment: Actually, I tried to set limits to values that callers can assign to those variables I mean v can only take values ​​between 0 and 100 m / s.

Comment: The code you posted does not do that. It makes the variables teta and v both contain a `Range` type. You'd need a custom setter to validate the value to do what you want.

Comment: Okay, I used the same logic. Thank you for that. How about the Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'Float' problem. How can i fix it ?